# wait_queue (linux) in cosumer producer

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am facing the building of a simple device driver on linux. In particular the device should act like a pipe, fifo behavior, and manage readers and writers. I decided to use spinlock and wait_queue in oder to control the thread flow and the concurrency. Since I need the fifo threads' operating, I made a simple list that let the thread obtain a position among all, so it can go when is the first (selective wake up).

```
typedef struct t_node
{
    struct task_struct *process;
    struct t_node *next;
    struct t_node *prev;
} t_node;
```

My question is about the condition given to wait_evet method. In fact both writers(readers) must sleep either if no space (data) is available or if a thread arrived earlier.

When a writer falls asleep, it should wait for being first of the list and available space:

```
wait_event_interruptible(queue, !node.prev && spaceEnough())
```

I would like finding a way to read condition in mutex way, without having any other thread writing that.
Note that a wake is called through:

```
wake_up_process(list.head)
```

How can i reach this?

Comment: Have you considered using `workqueue_struct`? It implements consumer-producer pattern and already able to spawn threads